# Get the Substrings within the List<string> collection using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.5

I've a collection list.

```
List<string> mycollections = new List<string>(new string[] 
            { 
                "MyImages/Temp/bus.jpg", 
                "MyImages/Temp/car.jpg", 
                "MyImages/Temp/truck.jpg", 
                "MyImages/Temp/plane.jpg", 
                "MyImages/Temp/ship.jpg",                 
            });
```

I required only files in a List such as`bus.jpg, car.jpg.....`. Here **i do not need** `"MyImages/Temp/"` portion of the string in the same list.

I tried with Substring and Split with Linq queries but couldn't get the expected result.

Answer (score 11):

Use [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of substring like:

```
var fileNames = mycollections.Select(r => Path.GetFileName(r)).ToList();
```

For output:

```
var fileNames = mycollections.Select(r => Path.GetFileName(r));
foreach (var item in fileNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);   
}
```

Output:

```
bus.jpg
car.jpg
truck.jpg
plane.jpg
ship.jpg
```

Comment: I think you can eta reduce

Comment: @miniBill, umm not really sure what you mean, are you saying that its performance can be improved ?

Comment: I think you can write (can't check right now) `var fileNames = mycollections.Select(Path.GetFileName).ToList();`

Comment: @miniBill, yes it can be written like that, same thing.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
mycollections.Select(s => s.Split('/').Last());
```

That will split each string by slashes and return the last item.